# Implementing microprofile health checks with EJB application

Tags: ejb, ear, open-liberty, microprofile

I have a EJB application (Ear) deployed on open liberty in kubernetes environment.

I am trying to implement health checks (liveliness and readiness) using the microprofile health feature supported by liberty (https://openliberty.io/docs/20.0.0.12/health-check-microservices.html).

Do I need to have seperate web application deployed or just implementing the health check classes in EJB module (without web module) works.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do. You can just add classes implementing livness/readiness to your existing web module or you can create separate one, that will just have various checks.

The best practice would be to have checks in the same module that is providing the service, in case you would later want to separate these services into different containers.

In Liberty checks from all web modules are aggregated and calculated together, so if you have multiple checks you may see something like this:

```
{
"checks":[
  {
     "data":{},
     "name":"myejb-bean",
     "status":"DOWN"
  },
  {
    "data":{},
    "name":"service1",
    "status":"UP"
    }],
"status":"DOWN"
}
```

Comment: Does  implementing liveness/readiness classes in EJB module (without web module)  in ear work?

Comment: @cooldev  No you need a web module, but in latest specs you may have EJBs in web module.